# How can you define a graph using ASN.1?

Tags: asn.1

Wikipedia on ["comparison of data-serialization formats"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_data-serialization_formats#Overview) says ASN.1 can serialize non-hierarchical structure (e.g., graphs) via "references" as follows:

> ASN.1 has X.681 (Information Object System), X.682 (Constraints), and X.683 (Parameterization) that allow for the precise specification of open types where the types of values can be identified by integers, by OIDs, etc. OIDs are a standard format for globally unique identifiers, as well as a standard notation ("absolute reference") for referencing a component of a value. For example, PKIX uses such notation in RFC 5912. With such notation (constraints on parameterized types using information object sets), generic ASN.1 tools/libraries can automatically encode/decode/resolve references within a document.

The book I've got (*ASN.1: The Tutorial And Reference* (Steedman, 1990) - quite old now but it was the reference for its time) doesn't describe this at all and my search-foo isn't sufficient to find an example on the web.  What does it look like?  And what is the terminology?

(E.g., can you provide an example of ASN.1 notation that can serialize a simple graph?)

Answer (score 1):

The confusion is around what is meant by a reference.  An ASN.1 type formally specifies a hierarchical value.  ASN.1 does not support non-hierarchical data.

The referenced features are defined in X.680, X.681, X.682, and X.683.  With table constraints and information objects, you can have a field whose type is determined by another field (e.g. an integer or OID), rather than specified in advance.  It is true that this feature allows tools to automatically read the identifier (the integer or OID), and thereby determine the actual type for the "open type" field, and then decode the open type according to its actual type.  However, this would be something more akin to dynamic types than to references or pointers in a data structure, which allow one to have a cyclical data structure.

There is no formal pointer or reference kind of thing in ASN.1 that, by the standard, identifies or points at some other part of the data structure.

Comment: Yes, it feels like loops / circlularity would be the problem. Might be made to work if the direction of edges between nodes didn't matter in the application and could be reversed: pre-processing could then "hierarchicalise" the graph. Another possibility is if the graph is actually a dictionary of (for example) int/Object, and the references are by int rather than memory pointer. That sounds like a slow graph, but possibly attractive in the sense it could be serialised in ASN.1 or other similar serialisation technologies.